# Auto launching of gear vr application when samsung s7 connected to Gear VR device

Tags: android, sdk, oculus, gear-vr

I have developed an android application using google VR SDK. It will works fine in Samsung S7.But when i attached to Gear VR device the Gear VR app launches,i can't run my application.How can i test my application with the gear VR device.
I have integrated the osig signature file.But unfortunately it never works.

I have seen that by installing some other apps from the playstore will help to run my application with the Gear VR device.But its not possible,b'ze i am in a testing phase and the requirement from client is different.I have to switch my application without installing any other apps.
Is there any way to do this..

Can someone help me to find the answer.?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.samsung.android.vr.application.mode"
        android:value="vr_only"/>
```

Add this into the your AndroidManifest.xml in application tag. Hope it helps

Comment: But now the problem is.. user has to login before get in to the app.after connecting to gear VR device, the app gets logout and restarts.The device doesnt allows the keyboard to pop up.So the user can't login and play the video

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off NFC on your device before adding to the Gear VR device.